# How to remove recursion, and write it functional and efficient way?

Tags: functional-style, vector, code-review, performance-tuning

I wish to implement the following recursion efficiently.

```
n = 999;
mat1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, n}, WorkingPrecision -> 20];

mat2 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, n}, WorkingPrecision -> 20];

ct = 1;
While [ct <= n - 1,

 mat1[[1, ct + 1]] = (const1*mat1[[1, ct]] + const2*mat1[[2, ct]])*mat2[[1, ct + 1]];

 mat1[[2, ct + 1]] = (const3*mat1[[1, ct]] + const4*mat1[[2, ct]])*mat2[[2, ct + 1]];

ct++;

];
```

I was thinking of using FoldList, but I have no idea how...

Edit: I've changed the number of constants.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do it using [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html) and some code vectorization

```
mat1[[1 ;; 2]] = Module[{ct = 1}, 
 NestList[({{const1, const2}, {const3, const4}}.#) mat2[[1 ;; 2, ++ct]] &, 
   mat1[[1 ;; 2, 1]], n - 1] //Transpose];
```

Assuming that the variables `const1` to `const4` have numerical values close enough to 1, e.g.

```
const1 = 1.0;
const2 = 0.9;
const3 = 0.95;
const4 = 1.2;
```

and therefore `mat1` will only contain machine size numbers, one can use a compiled function:

```
fC0 = Compile[{{m1, _Real, 1}, {m2, _Real, 1}},
 ({{const1, const2}, {const3, const4}}.m1) m2, 
 CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, CompilationTarget -> "C" ];
```

and then

```
mat1[[1 ;; 2]] = Module[{ct = 1}, 
 NestList[fC0[#, mat2[[1 ;; 2, ++ct]]] &, mat1[[1 ;; 2, 1]], n - 1] // Transpose];
```

One can even include the relevant parts of `mat2` in a compiled function

```
fC = Compile[{{m, _Real, 1}, {counter, _Integer, 0}},
 ({{const1, const2}, {const3, const4}}.m) mat2[[1 ;; 2, counter]], 
 CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

and then use

```
mat1[[1 ;; 2]] = Module[{ct = 1}, 
 NestList[fC[#, ++ct] &, mat1[[1 ;; 2, 1]], n - 1] // Transpose];
```

Comment: I still haven't had the time to study this. This weekend the latest I'll confirm that it works and accept it. Until then, +1. 
Many thanks for your effort. ;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. If you have trouble understanding this code, I can break it down into smaller pieces. But I don't want to spoil your learning experience.

Comment: I've detected a mistake in my question. I had to increase the number of variables 'const'. So, I changed a bit your answer to :  amat1[[1 ;; 2]] = 
  Module[{ct = 1}, 
   NestList[({{const1, const2}, {const3, const4}}. #) mat2[[1 ;; 2, ++ct]] &, 
     mat1[[1 ;; 2, 1]], n - 1] // Transpose];
The thing is the gain in efficiency is only of 0.002 or 0.001 seconds with n=999.  Is there a way to speed things up?

Comment: And thanks for the learning experience.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Using a compiled function reduces the computation time by a factor two on my PC.

Comment: I get the following error : « A C compiler cannot be found on your system. Please consult the \
documentation to learn how to set up suitable compilers. » I checked the documentation, and while following the examples, I got the same error...

Comment: See [Support Articles](http://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=C%20compiler).

Comment: What C compiler would you recommend for windows?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. I use the Visual Studio one on windows. http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12767 http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CCompilerDriver/tutorial/SpecificCompilers.html